# Calculate all Angles of my Triangle (all 3 sides given)

Tags: trigonometry

so id like to calculate the 3 given Angles as efficient as possible with trigometrics. Maybe with the law of Cosine. So if someone knows the formula for this id be happy to know.

Thanks for help

[image]

Comment: Didn't I already answer your question in the comments? What part about it don't you get, or that you're unsatisfied with? For reference, here is the [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3392088/calculate-all-angles-of-my-triangle-all-3-sides-given) that the OP has asked.

Comment: Also, performant is not a very commonly used word in English. I think you should replace it with 'efficient'.

Comment: The formula for the cosine rule is: $\cos C = \frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}$, where $a$ and $b$ are the adjacent sides to the angle you are trying to find, and $c$ is the opposite side. Which side is $a$ and which side is $b$ does not matter. (I gave you the formula in the comments of your last question.) And couldn't you search the formula up on Google?

Comment: Sry, i thought it would require a new topic, and what do i need to change at this formula to calculate angle A,B. I also have found a youtube tutorial where only calculates the angle C.

Comment: I got it, Cos B= (a²+c²-b²)/2ac, sry i dont know how to type it like you did.

Comment: It would be better if you include what you've already tried out, so anyone writing an answer can direct you the right way. Also, welcome to the mathematics stack exchange! [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax article to help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

The largest angle is opposite the longest side.  To find the largest angle, use the Law of Cosines 
$$c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab\cos\gamma$$
with $a = 7~\text{cm}$, $b = 5~\text{cm}$, and $c = 10~\text{cm}$.

Once you have solved for $\gamma$, use the Law of Sines
$$\frac{a}{\sin\alpha} = \frac{b}{\sin\beta} = \frac{c}{\sin\gamma}$$
to determine $\alpha$.  Keep in mind that there is only one possible value for $\alpha$ since $\alpha < \gamma$.

Once you have determined both $\alpha$ and $\gamma$, you can obtain $\beta$ by using the Angle Sum Theorem for Triangles, $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 180^\circ$.

Answer (score 0):

It is $$10^2=5^2+7^2-2\times 5\times 7\cos(\gamma)$$